# Removing configuration profiles via command line

Tags: macos, high-sierra

Is there a way to remove configuration profiles as root?

So far I have tried the following:

```
$ sudo su -
$ find / -name profile # trying in the following folder
$ cd /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Settings
$ chmod 777 com.apple.managed.PlugInKit.plist # operation not permitted
$ mv -f com.apple.managed.PlugInKit.plist com.apple.managed.PlugInKit.plist.old # operation not permitted
```

Any force moves, copies, removes, or chmods are not permitted even though I am an administrator.  I was able to remove them manually in the UI a few months ago but the system admin disabled that feature awhile back and now I'm trying to remove the restrictions on the filesystem.

Answer (score 3):

The `profiles` command gives you command line access to change profiles.

To remove a profile, use

```
sudo profiles -R -p identifier
```

To get the identifier of a profile if you don't have it already, find it in the list of profiles given by

```
sudo profiles -P
```

For another way to remove files in `/private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71949154/how-to-remove-a-automated-device-enrollment-profile-from-macos

Comment: If a profile has no name and the term "digital_health_restrictions" in the profile identifier, it's a profile generated by the Screen Time feature and can't be removed with the ``profiles`` command. Such profiles can be removed by disabling Screen Time.

Answer (score -1):

If you use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> it shows the hidden files in the Finder and you can edit them manually from there.

Comment: The OP specifically says they used to do this in the UI, but now no longer have the privileges to do this.